# Align equation with a better method than {split}?

Tags: equations, align

I've got the following code that I'm using and wondered if there was a way to get the minus sign (-) of the third term to align with the minus sign of the second term, or if there was a nicer way to set it out in general while keeping to the two column layout?

Also, is it possible to make the brackets outside the third term slightly larger?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}=-r\cos(\theta) - \frac{r^2(\cos^2(\theta) -\sin^2 (\theta))}{\sqrt{l^2-r^2\sin^2(\theta)}}
\\-\frac{r^4\sin^2(\theta) \cos^2 (\theta)}{(\sqrt{l^2-r^2\sin^2 \theta})^3}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{multicols*}{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\left(` and `right)` to make the brackets larger. Any reason why you don't want to use `align`?

Comment: The `align` environment is intended for aligning separate equations and will print two equation numbers. But `split` allows alignment, as Dr. Kumar points out.

Comment: You can use the `\nonumber` command to suppress assignment of equation numbers.

Comment: Notice that the `a4wide` package is considered obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: A minor point: You should be consistent in how you specify the angle. In most cases you have `(\theta)`, but you also use it without the `()`.  In this particular case I would just remove the `()` as the meaning is obvious, but that is a personal preference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `&` at proper places.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}=-r\cos(\theta) & % one & here <================
- \frac{r^2(\cos^2(\theta) -\sin^2 (\theta))}{\sqrt{l^2-r^2\sin^2(\theta)}}\\
 & % another & here <=============
 -\frac{r^4\sin^2(\theta) \cos^2 (\theta)}{\left(\sqrt{l^2-r^2\sin^2 \theta}\right)^3}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Then you will get the desired alignment. Also I have made the parenthesis around the third term bigger.

You can find the delimiters in `amsldoc.pdf` (ams documentation) bottom of page number 15. I have attached a screen shot for you.[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's much better. Have you any idea about the bracket sizing?

Comment: As Peter pointed out in a comment to your question, use `\left(` and `\right)` to allow for dynamic sizing of parenthesis, or whatever other symbol you want.

Comment: @Andy I edited my answer to include delimiters

Comment: @Andy, If you think that the answer has solved your problem, it's helpful to click on the green check mark next to it to "accept" the answer. This helps others who may encounter the same problem to find answers that work.